# Swift create custom initializer without parameters with custom name

Tags: swift

I want to create init for my class that might look something like this:

```
initWithSomeMode { // Not compilable
    self.init()
    self.customSetup()
}
```

Of course code above will not work, I just want to show what I want to achieve.

I can only see convenience init in Swift class, but in that case I need to add parameters, but I don't need them.

So, I might achieve this with convenience init something like this:

```
convenience init(foo: String?) {
    self.init()
    self.customSetup()
}
```

Is there any way to create custom init without parameters?

Comment: An initializer without parameters can be declared as `init()`. Do you mean you want a special name for your initializer?

Comment: @Sweeper yes, with custom name.

Comment: Any Class have no stored properties will be initialize without parameters

Comment: What is wrong with putting `self.customSetup()` in `init()`?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban What do you want exactly? And why not something like `init(with:)`?

Comment: @staticVoidMan i dont wan't to pass arguments to init.

Comment: @vadian because that would always call `customSetup()`. Maybe OP wants to inititialize an object with `customSetup()` explicitly, and not always.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a `static` method:

```
static func initWithSomeMode() -> YourClass {
    let obj = YourClass()
    obj.someCustomSetup()
    return obj
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
let yourClass = YourClass.initWithSomeMode()
```

Comment: thatnks, that will work, but it's kind of work around :) Sadly that i can't write exactly init method with custom name.

Comment: How do you expect it to work? Normally you wouldn't use any identifier to call an initialiser. @EvgeniyKleban

Comment: in obj-c that will be easily. initWithSmth(){ [self.init]; [self.setup]; return self ]; or something like this.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban  yeah but you don't call initialisers with names in swift. You just add () to your class name.

Comment: This may be convenient in some circumstances but this isn't actually an `init` method that follows the Swift init rules.

Comment: @pkamb True, but the other way is the one that manueGE suggested, which in my opinion, looks bad. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: I don't like the way it looks either but I think the answer is you *can't* have have a named `init` method without parameters. So you need to pass `Void` or `Bool` or something and then ignore it. In my case the actual `init` rules are essential so I can't use your "constructor" workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Also a workaround, but I tend to use this:

```
convenience init(withSomeMode: Void) {
    self.init()
    self.customSetup()
}
```

and then:

```
YourClass.init(withSomeMode: ())
```

it has some advantages over static method, like easier subclassing. But yes, still a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In current Swift you can only write a single no-parameter method that follows the Swift initialization process and rules: `init()`

To customize initialization, you must provide named input parameters: `init(with: String)`

There is no way to write a no-parameter "named initializer" to the left of the `(` and still have it be an initialization function that follows the `init` rules. Something like `initSpecial()` won't work.

> #### Initializers
>
> Initializers are called to create a new instance of a particular type. In its simplest form, an initializer is like an instance method **with no parameters**, written using the init keyword.
>
> #### Customizing Initialization
>
> You can **customize the initialization process with input parameters** and optional property types, or by assigning constant properties during initialization, as described in the following sections.
>
> https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html